# unable to read OAI XML from url with java FileUtils.getContents

Tags: java, spring, oai

I am trying to read a OAI xml from a web content with the following command (using java spring):

```
String xmlResponse = FileUtils.getContents(url, "UTF-8");
```

When setting the url to:

```
http://e-sdeir.uqac.ca/cgi/oai2-primo?verb=ListIdentifiers&metadataPrefix=oai_dc
```

The parameter: xmlResponse  is NULL.

When setting the url to:

```
http://ub-madoc.bib.uni-mannheim.de/cgi/oai2?verb=ListIdentifiers&metadataPrefix=oai_dc
```

The parameter: xmlResponse  contain the requested XML content from a web page.

Note that there are many other urls that resolve with NULL.

(If i not mistake it works in other place in the code - should I reset any parameter?).

Anyone know what may be the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Maybe a timeout problem? the problematic page have more data...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed with the timeout.
I increased the timeout and it works as expected.

Thanks any way!